# .NET Core Identity as UI show login page if not signed in

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I used Identity as UI to generate my login page,

My index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) {
 ... my html ...
}
```

When the user is not logged in this shows a Login button on the top right that redirects to the login page, I see the button has

`<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/VoyDashIdentity/Account/Login">Login</a>`

I want the index page to show the login page (or embedd it) if the user is not logged in without the need to click the login button, I tried:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) {
 ... my html ...
} else {
  Response.Redirect("VoyDash/Identity/Account/Login");
}
```

But this does not properly redirect to the area, all relative links (ie to bootstrap.css stop working correctly.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Base on the url from `href` , you can try : ``Response.Redirect("/VoyDashIdentity/Account/Login");``

But why not directly put `[Authorize]`attribute on your page to make sure only authenticated user could access your index page , otherwise user will be redirect to default login page  .

Comment: Have you ever try redirecting the user in the controller? For in the view, the response content is already rendering.

Comment: @NanYu I tried [Authorize] but I then get a default login page and no the one from ny scaffolded identity Login.cshtml .. why ?

Comment: No sure , but see below reply for customize the login page .

Answer (score 1):

By default , it will redirect user to the new login page after scaffolding .But you can always change the path using :

```
services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
    opt => {
        //configure your other properties
        opt.LoginPath = "/Login";
});
```

Make sure above config is under `AddDefaultIdentity` , otherwise `AddDefaultIdentity` will override the configuration .